# How to read an array passed to a view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a multidimensional array $data on the controller side. I populate $data[$group] with any group value, between G1 - G100. I then pass the array to a view via a controller:

```
$this->load->view('example', $data);
```

On the view-side I can then access the variable, for instance $G1, $G2. The problem is that I dont know before-hand what will be passed. I can try to access my variable like this in the view:

```
if (isset($G1)) echo $G1;
if (isset($G2)) echo $G2;
if (isset($G3)) echo $G3;
```

But this becomes highly unpractical when the group variable in $data[$group] on the controller-side can have many different values.

Is there any way to check from the view beforehand what is being sent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to know what will be passed, but you can put $data itself into an array and pass this array to the view, and in the view go through $data with a foreach:

```
//controller
$newdata = array(
    //maybe other data
    'data' => $data
);

$this->load->view('someview', $newdata);


//view

foreach($data as $key => $value){
    //do whatever you like
}
```

Comment: If you want to display something different if the array is empty, just wrap the loop in a if(count($data) > 0)

Comment: Thank you! After first using the parts of the array I needed, I did an unset on the known/used parts, and what remains is only the previously unknown part.